# React-redux connect() not subscribing to dispatched actions properly

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a simple component I'm trying to make work with redux. I map both props and dispatch actions, however only the props I initially get from the store work properly. I traced it all down to my actions: they are being dispatched, but respective reducers don't really do anything. Pretty simple stuff I came up with according to the tutorial and everything looks good to me, but I can't wrap my head around the problem here.

Here is a simplified version of the app:

```js
// index.js

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Search from './Search'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'

const root = document.querySelector('#app')
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Search/>
  </Provider>, root)
```

```js
// Search.js

import React from 'react'
import { setText } from '../../actions/appActions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    text: state.app.searchText
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    setText,
    dispatch
  }
}

class Search extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" onChange={() => this.props.setText("text")} value={this.props.text}/>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Search)
```

```js
// store.js

import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'

import app from './reducers/appReducer'

export default createStore(combineReducers({/*other non-relevant reducers*/, app}))
```

```js
// appActions.js
export function setText(text) {
  return {
    type: "APP_SET_TEXT",
    payload: text,
  }
}
```

```js
// appReducer.js

const initialState = {
  isSearchActive: true,
  searchText: "Text",
}

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "APP_SET_TEXT":
      console.log("fart")
      return {
        ...state,
        searchText: action.payload,
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to to is to simply make the input value change according to the redux state. I do get the text from `{this.props.text}`, the change handler `onChange={() => this.props.setText("text")}` is being dispatched, but the reducer for some reason fails to catch the action that was dispatched.

Comment: under mapStateToProps, you have an `app` property in state `text: state.app.searchText`, but I don't see that reflected in the reducer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    setText,
    dispatch
  }
}
```

change to

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    changeText: text => dispatch(setText(text)),
  }
}
```

And in your component use `this.props.changeText` function

Comment: I'm marking this one as correct since this is the first correct answer I got, despite there may be different correct answers. Can't upvote other questions, so yeah, thanks, that works.

Comment: Actually @jeremy's answer was the first one ;)

Comment: Yes, but it has an object assignment typo, so technically yours still is :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the mapDispatchToProps variable like the following:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    setText = (text) => dispatch(setText(text)),
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this

```
// MODIFYING DISPATHCER
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    changeText: data => dispatch(setText(data)),
  }
}
```

or

```
// CONNECT

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    setText
})(Search)
```

Answer (score 0):

as most of the answers suggests you can dispatch the actions or else you can simply have mapDispatchToProps an object.

```
mapDispatchToProps = {
   setText,
   dispatch
}
```

Your HOC connect should take care of dispatching not need to external definition

Answer (score 0):

Use `bindActionCreators` from `redux`

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  const setText = bindActionCreators(setText, dispatch);
  return setText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're mapping your dispatch to props like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    setText,
    dispatch
  }
}
```

You'll need to explicitly call `dispatch` in your component:

```
class Search extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  render() {
    const {dispatch, setText} = this.props; 
    return (
      <input type="text" onChange={() => dispatch(setText("text"))} value={this.props.text}/>
    )
  }
}
```

It is easier just to map dispatch to props like this: `setText = (text) => dispatch(setText(text))`